# Processing loops,millis and random

Tags: loops, random, progress-bar, processing

I want to draw a progress bar in processing which goes from white to black and completes within 2 t0 8 seconds everytime you run the program. The exact time should be random but within 2 and 8 seconds.

I have got the bar to run, I need help with making the bar complete at a random time between 2 and 8 seconds everytime i run the program. I am completely lost as This is for a uni assignment and Im only looking for psedocode to get me started. I have this so far

```java
int a;
  int k;
  int strokeC;
  boolean bar=true;


void setup (){
  size(500,300);
  background(255);
  colorMode(RGB,255);
  a = 130;
  k= a;
  strokeC = 255;
  rectMode(CENTER);
  noFill();
  rect(width/2,height/2,250,30);
}

void draw(){
 k++;

  for(int i=a, s=strokeC; i<=k && s>15; i++, s-- ) {
      stroke(s);
     line(i,140,i,160);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, you should use the `homework` tag for this sort of thing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could set a `Timer` for that

[There](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html) is a small tutorials about Timers and scheduling

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Reminder {
   Timer timer;

   public Reminder(int seconds) {
       timer = new Timer();
       timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);        
}

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Time's up!\n");
            timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       int random_num = Random.nextInt(7)+2; // Random num between 2-8; Random.nextInt(7) is from interval <0;7)
        new Reminder(random_num );
        System.out.println("Task scheduled.\n");
    }
}
```

Timer schedules RemindTask for amount of time, when time is up, run() method in RemindTask  is called.

Comment: how would I write this in processing?

Comment: How do you want the bar filled ? Continuosly or in one action. What programing language are you going to use ? Java ?

Comment: He is using `processing`, as stated

Answer (score 1):

Instead of incrementing `k` by one every frame, take a random amount of time between 2 and 8 seconds and set `k` at the appropriate amount every frame.

```
//your global variables...
int loadTime, startTime, endTime, barStart, barEnd;
void setup() {
  //your setup stuff...
  loadTime = random(2000, 8000);
  barStart = 130;
  barEnd = width - 130;
}
void draw() {
  if (frameCount == 1) {
    startTime = millis();
    endTime = startTime + loadTime;
  }
  k = map(millis, startTime, endTime, barStart, barEnd);
  //your for loop...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use `frameRate(your_number_here);`

It will slow down the main Processing 'draw' loop, as documented here: https://processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html